# Shiny App not working on Shiny Server with no log file present

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I have an application that works on a local R server (port 8787). When I move it to Shiny Server (port 3838), I receive the message

```
ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
```

And there is no log file present in `/var/log/shiny-server.log`

This is my configuration file:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as local user
run_as : HOME_USER:;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

#preserve_logs true;
  # Define a location at the base URL
 location / {

# Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

# Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;
preserve_logs true;
# When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
# an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
directory_index on;
 }
}
```

Could someone check my configuration file? Thank you

Comment: have you seen this: http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/os/latest/#home_user

Comment: Thank you! You set the wheels spinning... I'll post answer below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently sanitize error messages is true by default for my configuration.
Add
`options(shiny.sanitize.errors = FALSE)`  to your app.

In the configuration file (usually at `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`), place

```
sanitize_errors false;
preserve_logs true;
```

within server to resolve permanently.

Comment: `preserve_logs` needs to at the root level, not withing `server`.

Comment: may I suggest that you point to where the configuration file is in the answer? `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`

Answer (score 3):

Shiny also dumps errors and messages on the Console. 
You can access it by pressing Ctrl + Shift + J in your chrome or Opera browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my `server.R` I was using another R file: once I renamed it to `"global.R"` everything worked.

I started getting meaningful logs about missing packages. The packages need to be installed using `install.package("x", lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library")`.
 Make sure that the `"shiny"` user or whatever user you have specified in `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` has access to `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`.